# Need to get dynamic input field value using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

Need help on this
i need to get the dynamic input value entered using jquery

```
<?php 
      $elements=array('2','3');
    foreach($elements as $element){
        echo "<input type='text' name='name".$element."'><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='test' data-rel='".$element."'>get</a>";
    }
    ?>
</body>
<script>
$(document).on('click','a.test',function(){

var elemid=$(this).data('rel');
alert($("#name"+elemid+"").val());
});
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: .... and the problem is?

Comment: On click i am geeting the alert as undefined instead of the text box value

Comment: You would have better imho to use any jQuery traversing method to target specific input on anchor click e.g: `alert($(this).prev('input').val()`  http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/

Answer (score 3):

The selector is wrong, you're targeting by ID, when the element has a name

```
alert( $("[name = 'name" +elemid+ "']").val() );
```